# How can I fit the website page content to the size of the browser window if the window size is half of the screen size?

Tags: c#, winforms, selenium-webdriver

What it does now it's opening two windows of the edge browser each window size if half of the screen size and place both edge windows side by side.

each window of the browser is browsing another website.  The problem is that the site/s content not fit to the half size screen browser size.  if I will maximize one of the windows of the browser I will the complete website page content but since it's half size some of the site content not show.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Edge;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Firefox;

namespace Browser_Splitter
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            textBoxLeftUrl.Text = Properties.Settings.Default.textBoxLeftUrl;
            textBoxRightUrl.Text = Properties.Settings.Default.textBoxRightUrl;
        }

        private async void btnSplitter_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string url1 = textBoxLeftUrl.Text;
            string url2 = textBoxRightUrl.Text;

            // Get the screen dimensions
            Rectangle screenBounds = Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds;
            int screenWidth = screenBounds.Width;
            int screenHeight = screenBounds.Height;

            // Calculate the position and size for each Edge window
            Rectangle edge1Bounds = new Rectangle(screenBounds.Left, screenBounds.Top, screenWidth / 2, screenHeight);
            Rectangle edge2Bounds = new Rectangle(screenBounds.Left + screenWidth / 2, screenBounds.Top, screenWidth / 2, screenHeight);

            // Set up the Edge browser options
            EdgeOptions options1 = new EdgeOptions();
            options1.AddArguments("start-maximized");

            EdgeOptions options2 = new EdgeOptions();
            options2.AddArguments("start-maximized");

            // Set up the Edge driver service
            EdgeDriverService service1 = EdgeDriverService.CreateDefaultService();
            service1.HideCommandPromptWindow = true;

            EdgeDriverService service2 = EdgeDriverService.CreateDefaultService();
            service2.HideCommandPromptWindow = true;

            // Initialize the first WebDriver (Edge)
            IWebDriver driver1 = new EdgeDriver(service1, options1);
            driver1.Manage().Window.Position = new System.Drawing.Point(edge1Bounds.Left, edge1Bounds.Top);
            driver1.Manage().Window.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(edge1Bounds.Width, edge1Bounds.Height);

            // Initialize the second WebDriver (Edge)
            IWebDriver driver2 = new EdgeDriver(service2, options2);
            driver2.Manage().Window.Position = new System.Drawing.Point(edge2Bounds.Left, edge2Bounds.Top);
            driver2.Manage().Window.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(edge2Bounds.Width, edge2Bounds.Height);

            // Navigate to the URLs concurrently
            Task task1 = Task.Run(() => NavigateToUrl(driver1, url1));
            Task task2 = Task.Run(() => NavigateToUrl(driver2, url2));

            // Wait for both tasks to complete
            await Task.WhenAll(task1, task2);

            // Minimize the form
            this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Minimized;
        }

        private void NavigateToUrl(IWebDriver driver, string url)
        {
            // Navigate to the URL
            driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(url);
        }

        private void textBoxRightUrl_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Properties.Settings.Default.textBoxRightUrl = textBoxRightUrl.Text;
            Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
        }

        private void textBoxLeftUrl_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Properties.Settings.Default.textBoxLeftUrl = textBoxLeftUrl.Text;
            Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That's an issue of that site's stylesheet (if it has one, which is quite likely to be the case).